# Unit test failing when mocking python3

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

I am trying mock python3 `requests`

Here is my unit test:

```
from source.automation.my_web_session import MyWebSession
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('requests.Session', autospec=True)
def test_initialize_session(mock_session):
    # Arrange
    user_agent = 'mobile user agent'
    mock_session.headers = {'user-agent' : user_agent}
    csrftoken = 'csrftoken'
    mock_session.cookies = {'csrftoken' : csrftoken}
    my_web_session = MyWebSession()
    # Act
    print(my_web_session.session.cookies)
    # Assert
    assert my_web_session.session.cookies['csrftoken'] == csrftoken
```

Here is the class I am testing:

```
import requests

class MyWebSession:

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
```

I am trying to mock the setting and updating of the user agent. However, running my test I get the following error:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________ test_initialize_session ___________________________

mock_session = <MagicMock name='Session' spec='Session' id='81084944'>

    @patch('requests.Session', autospec=True)
    def test_initialize_session(mock_session):
        # Arrange
        user_agent = 'mobile user agent'
        mock_session.headers = {'user-agent' : user_agent}
        csrftoken = 'csrftoken'
        mock_session.cookies = {'csrftoken' : csrftoken}
        my_web_session = MyWebSession()
        # Act
>       print(my_web_session.session.cookies)

my_web_session_test.py:14:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <NonCallableMagicMock name='Session()' spec='Session' id='80148752'>
name = 'cookies'

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in {'_mock_methods', '_mock_unsafe'}:
            raise AttributeError(name)
        elif self._mock_methods is not None:
            if name not in self._mock_methods or name in _all_magics:
>               raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
E               AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'cookies'
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: I have edited the OP with the full traceback.

Comment: Add `mocked_session.headers = {}`.

Comment: Doing `mocked_session.headers = {'user-agent':'some_user_agent'}` works... but why?

Comment: Because now `mocked_session` does have an attribute `headers`.

Comment: @Goyo How do I go about mocking a `.get('https://www.google.com')` ? How do I specify that I want to mock an instance method of the object?

Comment: Of which object?

Comment: @Goyo The `requests.Session` that gets instantiated in the `MyWebSession` constructor.

Comment: For that you need to patch `request.Session` **before** calling the constructor.

Comment: @Goyo I don't think I am understanding this correctly. I have updated the OP with a more simplified example with what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are configuring the class (`mock_session` replaces `Session`) but you want to configure the instance, which is its return value. You can do that but it won't make a nice test. This works for me:

```
@patch('requests.Session', autospec=True)
def test_initialize_session(mock_session_cls):
    # Arrange
    mock_session = Mock(spec=[])
    user_agent = 'mobile user agent'
    mock_session.headers = {'user-agent' : user_agent}
    csrftoken = 'csrftoken'
    mock_session.cookies = {'csrftoken' : csrftoken}
    mock_session_cls.return_value = mock_session
    my_web_session = MyWebSession()
    # Act
    print(my_web_session.session.cookies)
    # Assert
    assert my_web_session.session.cookies['csrftoken'] == csrftoken
```

Some people might prefer the version below (I don't like it either):

```
def test_initialize_session():
    # Arrange
    mock_session = Mock(spec=[])
    user_agent = 'mobile user agent'
    mock_session.headers = {'user-agent' : user_agent}
    csrftoken = 'csrftoken'
    mock_session.cookies = {'csrftoken' : csrftoken}
    with patch('requests.Session', autospec=True, return_value=mock_session):
        my_web_session = MyWebSession()
    # Act
    print(my_web_session.session.cookies)
    # Assert
    assert my_web_session.session.cookies['csrftoken'] == csrftoken
```

What I find ugly about this test is that you are stubbing a test double to return another test double while you are interested in the second one only. That looks like one too many test doubles to me.

The underlying issue is that the creation of the `Session` instance is hidden inside the `__init__` method as an implementation detail, yet your test wants to control it as if it were public API. One way of solving this tension is creating the `Session` outside `MyWebSession` and passing the instance as a parameter. Then the test becomes more straightforward, you can get rid of the patching and the test double that you are not really interested in.

```
class MyWebSession:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session
```

And the test:

```
def test_initialize_session():
    # Arrange
    user_agent = 'mobile user agent'
    mock_session = Mock(spec=[])
    mock_session.headers = {'user-agent' : user_agent}
    csrftoken = 'csrftoken'
    mock_session.cookies = {'csrftoken' : csrftoken}
    my_web_session = MyWebSession(mock_session)
    # Act
    print(my_web_session.session.cookies)
    # Assert
    assert my_web_session.session.cookies['csrftoken'] == csrftoken
```

In the production code you would use something like

```
my_web_session = MyWebSession(requests.Session())
```

Another way is looking at `MyWebSession` as a thin wrapper providing a more convenient interface to `requests.Session` (if that is what you are trying to do here), then you might think of the tests as [characterization tests](http://wiki.c2.com/?CharacterizationTest) and not use test doubles at all.

Note that the `# Act` comment is misplaced and the call to `print` is irrelevant for the test (maybe you put it there for debugging?). That does not help but I left it as it is in your code to deviate as less as possible from it.